# Setting up MSMQ for clustering

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, cluster-computing

Can someone point me to some good resources about setting up MSMQ for queue clustering? I'm interested in help with:

1. Actually setting up the clustered MSMQ nodes, and making it function
2. Setting up an application to send messages to a clustered queue.
3. Setting up applications (at least 2) to read from the same clustered queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For item 1, here is a nice starting point: "[Building MSMQ cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mismail/building-an-msmq-cluster)".
You will find several other links in that article that will guide you further.

Microsoft also has a detailed document: "[Deploying Message Queuing (MSMQ) 3.0 in a Server Cluster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=349D6584-9510-46F5-904E-2C58FA16EB85&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)".

Items 2 and 3 seem to a little bit too much for just one thread.

You might want to use some framework like [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/) to work with the queues. NServiceBus comes with example projects that will help you to find a start.